# Looking for early paper about compiling object-oriented code

Tags: compiler-construction, oop

I remember reading a paper a long time ago that talked about object-oriented programming. I believe that this was from the early 1980s or perhaps even before then.

This was at the time when object-oriented programming was still done through pre-processors, and one thing that stuck with me is this: it argued that you could write code in either procedural or object-oriented fashion, and after preprocessing/compiling, you would end up with the exact same machine code.

Does anybody know which paper I'm talking about?

Comment: Object oriented programming in the early 80s was not done through a pre-processor - neither Simula nor Smalltalk used such a thing.

Comment: I should have said, "in C." I'm pretty sure this was about C (or maybe a similar language).

Answer (score 0):

Bjarne Stroustrup wrote [a paper](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/new_learning.pdf) more or less along the same lines. I kind of doubt it's *the* paper you're thinking of though, since it wasn't published until 1999, but perhaps it's useful anyway.